# Spyder app on OS X: keeping libraries up to date

Tags: python, spyder

I am using [Spyder](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder) to run a perfectly self contained instance of Python 3.x.  I need Python 3.x for some work related stuff, but I need it rarely and thus I want a perfectly self contained installation that will not interfere accidentally with any other thing on my machine.  I used [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) before but it just gives me far too much stuff and takes up far too much disk space.  Spyder App provides me a smaller package with all the libraries I need.  The question is:

aside from waiting for a new release of Spyder App, is there any way of keeping the various libraries that come with Spyder up to date?

Answer (score 0):

According to Carlos Cordoba in [this trhead](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/spyderlib/contained/spyderlib/tbbesDaJYUM/saJg7WB7CQAJ) the DMG is 100% self contained and thus the libraries that come with it cannot be updated.